# ASP.NET Core using UserManager or Entity Framework to validate extended form field

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've followed the procedure to scaffold the Razor Class Library as per: [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

I've also extended my model to include a property called `Office365DomainName`:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Office 365 Domain Name")]
    public string Office365DomainName { get; set; }
```

This property has been included in all the right places to ensure my SQL database gets populated as per the [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Now when a new user attempts to register, I'd like to check the database to make sure the `Office365DomainName` value doesn't already exist.

Here is what I've tried:

1. Injecting the `ApplicationDbContext` to my `Register.cshtml.cs` file and performing `var tenantResult = await _context.Tenant.FindAsync(Input.Office365DomainName);` however this gives me an exception about having a primary key to query. It makes sense...but I don't know what the PK would be without looking at the data first (catch 22).
2. Next, I tried UserManger's methods such as `var foo = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);`. However since no user is signed in yet, `User` doesn't exist.

I can't seem to find a built-in method from UserManager that meets my needs. So how would a person be able to query an entity without first knowing the primary key? I would imagine the `CreateAsync` method from UserManager does this checking to make sure other users don't exist; I simply want to add on to that functionality and check for my added field.

Here is my startup.cs relevant info:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Here is my `ApplicationDbContext.cs`:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<UserRegistrationExtension>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

My model representing data from the form is `UserRegistrationExtension`. My previous attempt was to create a `Tenant` object inside `ApplicationDbContext.cs` of type `UserRegistrationExtension`. Total guess there but I feel like I wasn't on the right track.

Basically I'm assuming I need to reference my `UserRegistrationExtension` type somewhere here but I don't know where to include it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is down to using `FindAsync`. That method specifically queries via primary key, so when you pass the `Office365DomainName` value, it's attempting to a find a record with that as a primary key, which it's obviously not. Instead, you should be doing something like:

```
await _context.Tenants.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Office365DomainName == Input.Office365DomainName);
```

Comment: edited the ask at the end. I was messing with creating a `Tenant` object inside my ApplicationDbContext file but that just gave me compile errors and no reference to the `.SingleOrDefaultAsync` method

Comment: scratch that. I had to put my object name `Tenant` in `ApplicationDbContent.cs` as follows: `public DbSet<UserRegistrationExtension> Tenants { get; set; }`. That worked! Thanks!